# Reindex url rewrite in cron at night 12

Tags: magento-1.9, url, cron, url-rewrite, reindex

I wants to run `URL-REWRITE INDEXING` at night 12. my need is to set cron at specific time. how to run **only** `URL-REWRITE INDEXING` alone by cron.

Answer (score 1):

There are commands available to do re-indexing in Magento.
To re-index only Catalog URL, use below command,

```
php -f /shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

You can re-index everything by

```
php -f /shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```

You can use these commands in cron setup like to run at midnight everyday.

```
0 0 * * * php -f /shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to write any code for that

just setup cron in crontab in your server

```
 0 0 * * * php -f MagentoDirPath/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```